# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Form POST method does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, http-post, razor-pages

I wrote a website in Asp.Net Core 3.1 version

The site works very well locally, but when I send it to the remote server, I noticed that the parameters were blank.

Unfortunately, I could not find the solution to this problem anywhere.

here are the codes

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetInTouch(string name, string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var result = _contactService.GetContact();
        if (!result.Success) return Redirect("/NotFound");

        var emailParameterResult = _emailParameterService.GetEmailParameter();
        if (!emailParameterResult.Success) return Redirect("/NotFound");

        var contactDto = _mapper.Map<ContactDto>(result.Data);
        var emailParamterDto = _mapper.Map<EmailParameterDto>(emailParameterResult.Data);

        var isSendMail = EmailSender.SendEmailMessage(contactDto.Email, name, email, subject, message, emailParamterDto);

        var resultMessage = isSendMail
            ? "<div class='alert alert-success mb-20'>Mesajınız gönderildi!</div>"
            : "<div class='alert alert-danger mb-20'>Mesaj gönderilirken bir hata meydana geldi.!</div>";

        return View(new ContactModel()
        {
            SendResultMessage = resultMessage,
            ContactDto = contactDto
        });
    }
```

View

```
            <div class="contact-from contact-shadow">
                <form asp-action="GetInTouch" asp-controller="Contact" method="post">
                    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="İsim Soyisim" required>
                    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Konu" required>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Mesajınız" required></textarea>
                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Gönder</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: When you say locally, do you mean when you with IIS express on visual studio or did you  publish it and deploy to IIS on your local machine?

Comment: `the parameters were blank` Do you try to capture request and check the actual data you post?

Comment: It works when I run the project through Visual Studio. When I run it in debug mode, parameters come to controller via form

Comment: `It works when I run the project through Visual Studio.` Ok, you already told that in your original post. Do you checked the request and the actual posted data to production site? Besides, do you enable any logging that would help troubleshoot exceptions?

Comment: The problem was not in the code.  I reconfigured the firewall in Plesk panel and my problem was resolved.  Thank you for your help.